# How to know the path of a particular software?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, software-sources, paths, startup-applications

Context:
I'm trying to make an application automatically start when I login. For this I need to select the `path` for the application.

[image]

Here are the paths I already looked into:

- `/sbin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/share/`

If this may help, the application I'm trying to find is called "[ScreenCloud](https://www.screencloud.net/)" and I downloaded it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

But I cannot find it, is there any way I can know where is installed a particular software? Because even if I found for this one, I would like to avoid having the same issue in the future.

Comment: Does it not work if you just type screencloud in the command line?

Comment: Did you get it from the snap store or from the Ubuntu software center because I cannot find it in any of the Ubuntu apt repositories.

Comment: @mchid You have to add the repository first. See: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-screencloud-ubuntu-16-04-17-04

Comment: @mchid I wasn't addressing OP's link but rather your comment: ***"because I cannot find it in any of the Ubuntu apt repositories"*** Screencloud can be installed from `.deb` package but you need to add PPA.

Comment: @mchid I knew the command was changed from `screencloud.sh` to `screencloud` and suspected it was moved out of `/opt`. That part of my answer was pointing out how `type` and `which` wouldn't find `screencloud` but `locate` would.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Right on. `screencloud.sh` actually still exists but I am not sure how it differs from `screencloud` other than the fact that the `.sh` file is a script and `screencloud` is not. I really am not familiar with this application. Under `/usr/bin/` there is a `screencloud`, a `screencloud.sh`, and also a `screencloud-` followed by the version number sort of like how `gimp` is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Find the path of an executable**

**Best way**

- `type executable`

Check out [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) to learn more about how `type` is better. (Thanks, comments!)

**Other ways**

- `whereis executable`
- `which executable`

Those commands only search in the PATH variable (`echo $PATH`), thus they are not valid in some cases (built-in functions, aliases, or bash functions, and more).

Comment: incredibly enough this was not yet a question on ask ubuntu. good question @Ced!

Comment: Indeed, I can hardly believe it!

Comment: All these years I have been using the find command to locate the binary but I must admit that ```whereis``` returns much better results

Comment: @Gordster I just edited my answer to add the `which` command, which I remembered by reading your comment (thank you!).

Comment: I found out from another question that `type` is preferred over `which` as it's a shell builtin and can determine whether a command is an alias. That was new to me too!

Comment: I'd use the locate command.  First type sudo updatedb.  Then type locate screencloud.

Comment: See here for a (long) explanation of why `type` is preferred: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Comment: Edited to reflect your comments ;)

Comment: @mchid the points in the answer all apply. Including the "Use Cases" section which points out that `which` is indeed useful in the specific context of shell scripts. Outside that context, however, `type` is almost always the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

## Find command location inside or outside of path

Assume you want to find the location of `uname`, a program that lists system information. If you want to know what directory the top level command is stored in you have a number of options:

```
$ which uname
/bin/uname

$ type -a uname
uname is /bin/uname

$ command -v uname
/bin/uname

$ locate uname
/bin/uname
    (... SNIP dozens of Windows files on C & D ...)
/usr/lib/klibc/bin/uname
/usr/lib/plainbox-provider-resource-generic/bin/uname_resource
/usr/share/man/man1/uname.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/oldolduname.2.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/olduname.2.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/uname.2.gz
```

#### Locate advantages

The last option `locate` returns all files containing `uname` not just the program that is run from the command prompt.

The advantage of `locate` is it will find commands **not in** your search path. `type -a` (preferred over simple `type`) and `which` will only find commands in your search path. To see your search path use `echo $PATH`.

Take for example this answer in [How to start screencloud?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145889) :

> Try...
>
> ```
> /opt/screencloud/screencloud.sh
> ```

The `locate screencloud` command will find it but `which screencloud` and `type -a screencloud` will not because:

- The full name is `screencloud.sh` and only `locate` command searches on partial match.
- `/opt/screencloud` probably isn't in the search path. `which` and `type` only look for executable files in search path.

**Note:** This is an older answer. Modern ScreenCloud is called with `screencloud`.

Locate's advantage over the `find` command is it can be hundreds or even thousands of times faster. Also running `find` starting from `/` will give many permission errors you won't experience with `locate`.

#### Locate disadvantages

If you just installed the program today you will need to use `sudo updatedb` to update locate's database.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to list all of your `$PATH` directories:

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

Use the following command to find the full path for `screencloud`:

```
for i in $(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'); do find $i/screencloud* 2>@1; done
```

---

If you used `apt`, `apt-get`, or the Ubuntu Software Center to install the package, you can use the following command to find the full path:

```
dpkg -L screencloud | grep bin
```

Assuming you used [this repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/), you should be able to find `screencloud`
 in `/usr/bin/`.

The full path is:

```
/usr/bin/screencloud
```

or

```
/usr/bin/screencloud-*
```

---

However, if you used the [snapcraft store](https://snapcraft.io/screencloud) according to the [link you provided](https://www.screencloud.net/) in your question, then the path would be under the following directory:

```
/snap/bin
```

[more info](https://docs.snapcraft.io/system-snap-directory)

Also, please remember that Ubuntu is case sensitive so you must use all lowercase with no capital letters.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer, you won an upvote:)

Comment: It was effectively under `/snap/bin`!